# How to bring back the margin editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes, this window gets disappeared. I observed it happens when I return to this panel after viewing all the attributes (View all attributes at the bottom of the toolbar). How to bring it back?

In other words, how to toggle this tool's visibility?

[image: Margin editor]

Answer (score 0):

There is one option(Attributes) at Right-Bottom side in Android Studio. click on Attributes to get back that view.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio provides the Layout Editor for quickly building layouts. It lets you drag UI elements to a visual design and blueprint view, position the elements in the layout, add constraints, and set attributes.
In design tab of your xml file you can find the blueprint icon there[image]
If there is no blueprint, click the Show Blueprint icon in the toolbar.

There is 3 option,
1 - Design
2 - Blueprint
3 - Design+Blueprint

Please select 3 option if you want to see that section.

OR 
You can toggle the screen by clicking the attribute option.

Thanks.